# Creating and Defining a SAS Array on MVS SAS

Tags: sas, mainframe, jcl, zos, mvs

I need to build an array in SAS on MVS

I tried using

```
ARRAY MONTHS[12] $3 ('JAN' 'FEB' 'MAR' ... 'DEC');
```

but that is not working

Any suggestions?

Comment: So the ERROR message is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended figuring it out

```
ARRAY MONTHS{*} JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an MVS implementation to test on.

But why not try the MONNAME3. format?

```
1240  data test;
1241  x=1;
1242  y = put(x,monname3.);
1243  put x= y=;
1244  run;

x=1 y=Jan
```